# ggplot2: reorder x axis label by factor of levels doesn't work

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to draw a plot with `x-axis` labels equal to `c("chr","lab1","lab3","lab10")`
But when I set up the level of `x-axis`, it seems the reorder of `x-axis` doesn't work.
Can anyone help me solve the problem?
I don't know why I cannot change the order of `x-axis` labels.

[image]

```
library(ggplot2)
library(viridis)

set.seed(123)
data.df=data.frame(gene=c("APC","NF2","APC","NF2","APC","NF2","APC","NF2"),
                   variable=c("lab1","lab1","lab3","lab3","lab10","lab10","chr","chr"),
                   value=c(sample.int(100, 6),5,22))

ggplot(data.df, aes(x=factor(variable, level = c("chr",paste0("lab",c(1,3,10)))),
                    y=factor(gene, level = c("NF2","APC")))) + 
  geom_tile(data=filter(data.df,variable != 'chr'), 
            aes(fill= value),colour='white') +  
  geom_point(data = filter(data.df,variable=="chr"),
             aes(col=as.factor(value)))+ 
  scale_fill_viridis_b()
```

===============

An update about the dataset, my entire dataset includes 1254 obs. of  3 variables.

To set up the level of variable seems work for this example, but it doesn't work for my entire dataset.

```
> str(melt.df)
'data.frame':   1254 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ gene    : Factor w/ 57 levels "NF2","TNNI3",..: 29 16 39 49 18 31 9 20 52 46 ...
 $ variable: Factor w/ 22 levels "chromosome_name",..: 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ value   : num  100 100 99.8 100 100 ...
```

Final update, I find a way to solve my problem by add `+ scale_x_discrete(limits = c("chr",paste0("lab",c(1,3,10))))`

Thank Ricardo Semião e Castro and TarJae for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ggplot2 plots any factor variable in the order of their levels, and by default, R sets the levels of a factor alphabetically, such that `"lab10"` (which starts with a 1) is before `"lab3"`. To correct this, reorder the levels of your variable:

```
factor(data.df$variable, c("chr","lab1","lab3","lab10"))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this works for the example above, however, it doesn't work for my entire datasets. By the way,  do you know why `aes(x=factor(variable, level = c("chr","lab1","lab3","lab10")))` doesn't work in my case?

Comment: I don't know why changing the levels inside ggplot doesn't work, but it's normally good to modify the dataset anyway. Post your dataset (paste the output from `dput(data.df)`) and i'll have a look at it.

Comment: Thanks. I find a way to fix the problem by add `+ scale_x_discrete(limits = c("chr",paste0("lab",c(1:4,6:7,9:14))))`